# NPE in JBossWS on JBoss 4.2.2 with jmxremote enabled

Tags: java, jboss, jmx, jconsole, jbossws

I am trying to set up JBoss 4.2.2 and JConsole for remote monitoring.  As per many of the how-to's I have found on the web to do this you need to enable jmxremote by setting the following options in run.conf.  (I realize the other two opts disable authentication)

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=11099"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
```

Which results in the following exception:

```
13:06:56,418 INFO [TomcatDeployer] performDeployInternal :: deploy, ctxPath=/services, warUrl=.../tmp/deploy/tmp34585xxxxxxxxx.ear-contents/mDate-Services-exp.war/
13:06:57,706 WARN [AbstractServerConfig] getWebServicePort :: Unable to calculate 'WebServicePort', using default '8080'
13:06:57,711 WARN [AbstractServerConfig] getWebServicePort :: Unable to calculate 'WebServicePort', using default '8080'
13:06:58,070 WARN [AbstractServerConfig] getWebServicePort :: Unable to calculate 'WebServicePort', using default '8080'
13:06:58,071 WARN [AbstractServerConfig] getWebServicePort :: Unable to calculate 'WebServicePort', using default '8080'
13:06:58,138 ERROR [MainDeployer] start :: Could not start deployment: file:/opt/jboss-4.2.2.GA/server/default/tmp/deploy/tmp34585xxxxxxxxx.ear-contents/xxxxx-Services.war
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.WSDLFilePublisher.getPublishLocation(WSDLFilePublisher.java:303)
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.WSDLFilePublisher.publishWsdlFiles(WSDLFilePublisher.java:103)
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.PublishContractDeploymentAspect.create(PublishContractDeploymentAspect.java:52)
at org.jboss.wsf.framework.deployment.DeploymentAspectManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentAspectManagerImpl.java:115)
at org.jboss.wsf.container.jboss42.ArchiveDeployerHook.deploy(ArchiveDeployerHook.java:97) 
...
```

My application uses JWS which according to this bug:

https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/JBWS-1943

Suggests this workaround:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djavax.management.builder.initial=org.jboss.system.server.jmx.MBeanServerBuilderImpl"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.platform.mbeanserver"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote"
```

(https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/JBossWS-FAQ#jive_content_id_How_to_use_JDK_JMX_JConsole_with_JBossWS)

I've tried that however that then throws the following exception while trying to deploy a sar file in my ear which only contains on class which implements Schedulable for a couple of scheduled jobs my application requires:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at EDU.oswego.cs.dl.util.concurrent.ConcurrentReaderHashMap.hash(ConcurrentReaderHashMap.java:298)
at EDU.oswego.cs.dl.util.concurrent.ConcurrentReaderHashMap.get(ConcurrentReaderHashMap.java:410)
at org.jboss.mx.server.registry.BasicMBeanRegistry.getMBeanMap(BasicMBeanRegistry.java:959)
at org.jboss.mx.server.registry.BasicMBeanRegistry.contains(BasicMBeanRegistry.java:577)
```

Any suggestions on where to go from here?

EDIT:

I have also tried the following variation:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -DmbipropertyFile=../server/default/conf/mbi.properties  -DpropertyFile=../server/default/conf/mdate.properties -Dwicket.configuration=DEVELOPMENT"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djavax.management.builder.initial=org.jboss.system.server.jmx.MBeanServerBuilderImpl"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.platform.mbeanserver"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote"
```

I'm using JDK 1.6.0_01-b06

Comment: The problem was fixed in JBoss 4.2.3

Answer (score 2):

I have honestly never tried this remoting approach. But, if both your client machine and the server happen to both be linux boxes or similar *nixes with SSH, then you can `ssh -XCA` to the server and start JConsole *on the server* and have the GUI display on your client machine with X port forwarding. A JConsole running locally to the server JVM you want to monitor *should* not have any trouble connecting.

I personally think that's a nifty trick but I realize that it dosn't *really* solve the problem of getting JConsole to connect remotely through JWS.

Comment: I've tried that and it works.  However, JConsole is pretty resource intensive and it would have to be running for sometime to be useful.  In addition X forwarding is so painfully slow with the graphs/updating that it's pretty much unusable anyway.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would do is to delete both /tmp and /work directories under JBoss /default and redeploy the WAR.  If that doesn't, I would upgrade the JDK to use a more recent version of 1.6.  1.6.0_01 is pretty old.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a specific reason you're trying to use WS to access the mbean server, but with JConsole you can directly access a remote JVM. To do this use "service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://<remote-machine>:<port>/jmxrmi" (where <remote-machine> is whatever machine your trying to connect to and <port> is 11099) as the remote process.

I have used this to connect to any 1.6 JVM that exposes an mbean server (JBoss, ActiveMQ, etc).

Comment: You misread the question.  I'm not using WS to access the mbean server.  I'm using WS in the application.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is related, but JBoss has a tendency to redirect to itself. If you connect to a host, say jboss.localdomain:3873, wanting to connect to a ejb, JBoss might lookup its own hostname and redirect to the address it gets from there. If you have a public hostname, it might find that instead (say jboss.publicdomain.com), and tell the client to reconnect to jboss.publicdomain.com:1099. Depending on your DNS, this might or might not be a reachable address from your client.

There are various varations of this problem, and as a bonus, sometimes the initial "connection check" works, so the client app deploys, but fails later on connect.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue, but with JBoss Seam: take a look at [JBSEAM-4029](https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/JBSEAM-4029). As one of the workarounds it suggests to override the class running into the NPE - in Seam's case the `JBossClusterMonitor`.

I bet the JWS code is running into exact same issue, i.e. ending up calling `MBeanServerFactory.findMBeanServer(null)` at some point in time. The stack trace should reveal which exact class does this.